# How to fool an iframe thinking it is the TOP location

Tags: javascript, php, iframe

I have an iframe with this CSS rule in the header section of the page:

```
html{
  display:none;
}
```

and then this javascript code:

```
if (self == top)
  document.documentElement.style.display = 'block';
else
  top.location = self.location;
```

Is it possible to trick it thinking to be the top ?
I know that using `X-Frame-Options` header with SAMEORIGIN is a better protection, but i wanted just to know if it is possible to break this one and eventually how so that i can give it away without the need of modify php code.

Note: the page is mine.

Comment: Sounds like the owner of the content does not want you to display it in an iframe. Perhaps they have an api you can use instead.

Comment: Ask the one who created the page you want to display in the `iframe` how you can do that. Because the code clearly shows that you don't have to do that and even if you don't create about that you need to expect that a working solution will break in future.

Comment: The page is mine and i'm trying to look if it's possible to break it. I am trying to find if i can sleep without worrying that somebody is making clickjacking on my page or i must absolutely add other protections like the X-Frame-Options header, but it would be harder to explain to other people how to do it and that they must do it.